# Ubuntu 20.04 LTS freeze after login (BIOS mode UEFI) (AMD64)

Tags: boot, dual-boot, 20.04, login, freeze

Last night dual booted Ubuntu 20 04 lts with my Windows 10. Everything was Alright back then. But today when I booted my laptop to Ubuntu it took a little more time to boot and when I logged in after giving my password it just freezed at a purple screen. Not even the cursor is visible. Please Help!

Comment: Can you get in console, press any variation of the function keyrs ctrl+alt+f1 or ctrl+alt+f2...f3., do you get a terminal

Answer (score 0):

I Dual booted Ubuntu 20.04 with my Windows 10. Everything was Alright back then. But today when I booted my machine to Ubuntu and after signing in , its desktop screen just freezed . Even not able to open terminal window.
thank in advance to all techie to look into and offer valuable suggestions.